# Equation: If the equilibrium level of GDP is $21,500, what is the marginal propensity to consume?

Tags: gdp, equilibrium-selection

Equations for $C$, $I$, $G$, and $NX$ are given below. If the equilibrium level of $GDP$ is $\$21,500$, what is the marginal propensity to consume?

$$C = 1,500 + (MPC)\cdot Y$$
$$I = 1,000$$
$$G = 2,000$$
$$NX = -200$$

Comment: Please provide your tentative solution so that we can get what is not clear to you

Answer (score 0):

In equilibrium,

Y = AD                   ________________________             ( eq 1)

AD= C + I + G + NX

AD= 1,500 + cY + 1,000 + 2,000 - 200

Or AD = 4,300 +cY
Or Y = 4,300 +cY  ------(from 1)

Or (1-c)Y=4,300

Or 1-c = 4,300/Y = 4,300/21,500 = 0.2

Or 1-c = 0.2

Or **c = 0.8**

Hope this helps